# How get the amount of elements/fields of a node

Tags: xml, xpath, spring-test-mvc

I am working with

- Spring MVC
- Spring MVC Testing

In Spring MVC, assuming that a `@Controller` working with `@ResponseBody` returns a domain object represented in XML format and through `print()` method I can confirm the following:

```
Body = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persona>
    <id>100</id>
    <nombre>Jesús Você</nombre>
    <apellido>"Mão Nuñez"</apellido>
    <fecha>2015-12-05T22:00:07.756-05:00</fecha>
</persona>
```

I have the following for Spring MVC Testing:

```
resultActions.andExpect(xpath("persona").exists())
             .andExpect(xpath("persona").nodeCount(1))

             .andExpect(xpath("persona/id").exists())
             .andExpect(xpath("persona/id").string("100"))
             .andExpect(xpath("persona/nombre").exists())
             .andExpect(xpath("persona/nombre").string("Jesús Você"))
             .andExpect(xpath("persona/apellido").exists())
             .andExpect(xpath("persona/apellido").string("Mão Nuñez"))
             .andExpect(xpath("persona/fecha").exists())
```

Until here all work fine.

But again, for:

```
<persona>
    <id>100</id>
    <nombre>Jesús Você</nombre>
    <apellido>"Mão Nuñez"</apellido>
    <fecha>2015-12-05T22:00:07.756-05:00</fecha>
</persona>
```

Observe *persona* element/node contains four elements:

- id
- nombre
- apellido
- fecha

How through `xpath` I can get from the persona element/node that count of four from that set of fields/elements?

Something similar from `jsonPath` such as:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath('$.*', hasSize(4) ))
```

It should be applied for a collection too:

```
<persona-collection>
    <persona>
        <id>88</id>
        <nombre>Manuel</nombre>
        <apellido>Jordan</apellido>
        <fecha>2015-12-05T22:00:07.750-05:00</fecha>
    </persona>
    <persona>
        <id>87</id>
        <nombre>Leonardo</nombre>
        <apellido>Jordan</apellido>
        <fecha>2015-12-05T22:00:07.750-05:00</fecha>
    </persona>
…
</persona-collection>
```

Where from each node or element of the collection I want confirm it has the four elements/fields.

Something similar from `jsonPath` such as:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath('$',hasSize(5)))
.andExpect(jsonPath('$[0]').exists())
.andExpect(jsonPath('$[0].*', hasSize(4)))
…

.andExpect(jsonPath('$[4]').exists())
.andExpect(jsonPath('$[4].*', hasSize(4)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: `xpath('count(persona/*)')`

Comment: `xpath("persona//").nodeCount(4)` should work

Comment: @eLRuLL how is expected to compare `xpath('count(persona/*)')` against 4?

Comment: @CroWell `xpath("persona//").nodeCount(4)` is almost correct, there is a typo, must be `xpath("persona/*").nodeCount(4)`. Observe `//` to `/*`

Comment: Thanks to both by your replies.

Comment: Ok, must be `xpath('count(persona/*)').number(4)`

Comment: Add your replies how a solution. It to mark how the solution. Thanks